# What is wrong with my OpenLayers Vector layer?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to create an OpenLayers map with 2 layers:

1. The actual map.
2. A red dot, which marks the center of the city.

I wrote following code:

```
function createView() {
    return new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([132.183333, 43.35], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 13
    });
}
function createMapLayer() {
    return new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'}),
        visibility: true
    });
}

function createCenterOfCityLayer() {
    var coordinates = [132.183333, 43.35];
    var features = new Array(1);

    features[0] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));

    var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
    });

    var style = [new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 100,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'red'
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'red'
        })
    })];

    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: style
    });

    return layer;
}

function createMap() {
    return new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            createMapLayer(),
            createCenterOfCityLayer()
        ],
        view: createView()
    });
}
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('city-editor', [  ]);

    app.controller('CityEditorController', function(){
        this.map = createMap();
    });
})();
```

The first layer (actual map) is created inside the `createMapLayer` function, the red dot layer - in `createCenterOfCityLayer`. But when I open the web page, no red dot is displayed at the center of the view.

You can find the entire source code [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s35/sh/3853e6dc-1575-4b8e-a09c-bd775fd1b5c9/cc6323bd6077927085ec0cb611839eab).

What is wrong with my code (how can I change it so that the red dot is displayed at point `[132.183333, 43.35]`) ?

Comment: You transform the center coordinate, but not the city coordinate. Are you sure that your map and your data uses the same coordinate system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector data must be in the same projection of your view, so you must translate your vector coordinates too from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857.

Another options, instead make the transform by hand is to use the `projection` property within the vector source.

Cheers.